# How to do recording in Jmeter and in loadrunner at same time

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have one requirement, I need to record the script in Jmeter and in loadrunner at same time. Please suggest how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the nature of your request, I would rather first recorded the test in LoadRunner and then [replayed in using LoadRunner and recorded it in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-loadrunner-tests-jmeter/), however if this is something you really need:

1. I would recommend using [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) browser because it has separate proxy configuration
2. [Configure Firefox to use JMeter as the Proxy](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/connection-settings-firefox)

   [image]
3. [Start JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

   [image]
4. Start recording in LoadRunner.

   [image]
5. That's it, you should be able to perform your tests in browser and both JMeter and LoadRunner will capture the requests

Comment: Here, I need to record in one tool wether in Jmeter or in loadrunner but requests should be captured both in Jmeter and loadrunner